# Why is R "ar" instead of "er"?

Tags: letters-of-the-alphabet

In the names of letters, the e is predominant: ef, em, el, es. Why is R different? Why ar instead of er?

Comment: Because it makes for better pirate jokes. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consonant /r/ has had many effects on the vowels preceding it over the history of the English language.  In fact, on page 724 of *English Pronunciation 1500-1700* (1968), E. J. Dobson writes:

> No consonant exercises greater or more varied influence on the development of the words in ME and ModE than *r*.

The name of all of these letters comes from Latin and they originally all had the same vowel, but in Late Middle English /r/ tended to affect the quality of vowels preceding it, and in the case of /e/ that meant a lowering from /er/ to /ar/.

This affected many words; for example, Early Middle English *derk* became Late Middle English *dark*.  Because the /r/ in the pronunciation of the letter R was still pronounced in British English at this time, it was affected as well.  However, this sound change did not affect the other letter names because they had consonants other than /r/.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it is part of a phonological change that took place over the centuries.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R) has a paragraph on this:

> The name of the letter in Latin was er (/ɛr/), following the pattern of other letters representing continuants, such as F, L, M, N and S. This name is preserved in French and many other languages. In Middle English, the name of the letter changed from /ɛr/ to /ar/, following a pattern exhibited in many other words such as farm (compare French ferme), and star (compare German Stern).